Why is my score for the [failure] tag wrong?
Tracking the [failure] bronze tag badge, it gives me a score of 21 from 2 answers. But, this is wrong. I have 7 answers (+1 deleted) with an overall score of 50 (or 49 counting the deleted one). This does not happen on other sites in the network, or on other tags here. The total score and answer count appears correctly at the select your next badge popup, however. What is going wrong here?

I can't see the incorrect data you see.
When I look at your page I see 22 non-wiki questions 87 score, 7 non-wiki answers, 46 score.
I'm guessing something is cached incorrectly on your side and will sort itself at some point.

Well I rechecked and now its working so...thanks
